# SQL Query inserting into a table data present in other tables

Tags: sql, mysqli

1. category table
2. sub category Table

Structure for which is Category Table

```
id, name, article.
1, About, About content
2, Contact Us, Call us on
```

AND for sub-category-table

```
id, cat_id, name 
1,  1, History
2,  1, Offices
```

Can someone please tell me a single SQL query,t hat can insert data into sub-category table I have provided (Category Table name eg: **About** but not id, & Sub Category name : Carrer).  I can use the  Category Table name for finding the corresponding id and use it for insertion into cat_id BUT how?

Comment: Didn't understood your question

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out your question

But the basic sql is

```
Insert SomeTable(SomeColumn1,... SomeColumn99) 
  Select OtherColumn1,.. OtheColumn99 From SomeOtherTable Where ....
```